# Sum of a Generalized Arithmetico-Geometric Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Is there any exact form for the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^p r^k $$ for $p \in (0,1)$? I know we can upper bound it with $$\frac{r}{(1-r)^2}$$ by comparing to the arithmetico-geometric sum, but I would like a more exact answer.

Comment: There is probably no general closed form for this sum.

Comment: Wait... is it $p\in(0,1)$ or $r\in(0,1)$?

Comment: $p \in (0,1)$, although $r \in [0,1)$ should be a necessary requirement.

Comment: Yeah, no chance for a closed form then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^p\, r^k=\text{Li}_{-p}(r)$$ where appears the [polylogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Have a look at the paragraph *Particular values* in the linked page for the negative index.